# Implementing typescript based react template in new/existing project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to make a ReactJS project with the help of a **pre-defined template** (e.g., the [Doar template](https://preview.themeforest.net/item/doar-responsive-react-admin-template/full_screen_preview/32403518?_ga=2.5627760.2136969192.1680966187-1800577324.1680966187)). I need help setting up the template in a new/existing React project. I know that first I had to change my .js/.jsx to .tx/.tsx, which is not a big task. I am a bit confused about where to add files and how to call the template files in the project. To give you a much clearer explanation, suppose we are making a project with .js components and we need to embed a ReactJS template (with .js or.jsx components). What I will do is import JS and CSS files in index.html. But how does this thing work with .ts components?

I am also adding screenshot to show the project structure of the template.
[image: Template project structure]

Comment: Hi, NinjaCoderDotCom. A build step is needed to generate bundled js and point to it from a HTML page. I have found vite tooling to be a very easy starting point for this - a radical improvement on create-react-app. It has a built-in configuration for Typescript as per this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-p9e1ps?file=index.html&terminal=dev The instructions to create your own are https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project Choose react-ts and then you can start putting your components in e.g. `main.ts`